# Send logic over Http

Tags: c#, http, logic, func

I'm trying to send a class that contains a Function over http.
Can this be accomplished?

Its supposed to work like this:

1) Client contacts Web.API.
2) Web.API returns class with the Function
3) Client executes Function.

Class will look a bit like this :

```
 public class UploadTicket
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public List<Tuple<string, string>> Headers { get; set; }

    public Func<string> SpecialFunction { get; set; }
}
```

I need this function to alter the uploadurl by appending an ID every time a package is sent - but only if it's to certain dataproviders, and in other cases uploadurls must be modified in other ways. I need to do it this way, so i can keep the client side code as general as possible.

Comment: Why can't the function exist on the client? What overall problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The simple answer - you cannot do this. You cannot send a C# method over HTTP and, moreover, execute C# method in JS. You need to implement this logic either at client-side or server-side and use it.

Comment: @DGibbs The function needs to be generated on the server side, because the logic will be different depending on whom the client needs to contact - and basicly i need to create a method on the client side that will never need to be modified again - all must be handled on the server side if possible.

Comment: @OneBigQuestion `"because the logic will be different depending on whom the client needs to contact"` - use a parameter to identify who the client needs to contact?

Comment: @Yeldar Bummer.. I was afraid it had to be done that way..

Comment: @DGibs I would still need to implement logic on the client side every time a new dataprovider was added then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds a little goofy but yeah you can, on the condition that you send source to the client and not some pre-compiled version (otherwise it'd really be a gaping security hole). Just use the [C# runtime compiler](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/304655). But it implies the client is C#, that's why it sounds goofy.

This is actually a common pattern everybody uses every day. Think of the web browser that hits a web server and gets a page with javascript in it. The same thing happens. The browser compiles the JS and executes it, even though the source was produced remotely.

Comment: I looked into it, unfortunatly i'm creating this project in xamarin, and the projects cannot share the C# runtime compiler across platforms - but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've done that before with MonoDevelop, which is basically an old version of xamarin. You just need Mono.CSharp.dll in your runtime.